# Rails to_json(methods: => [...]) for different ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In Rails, i have an object called `values` that could be 1 of 20 kinds of ActiveRecord, and in only 1 of them there's a method(may be the wrong term, rails newbie) that can add a customized field in returned JSON object where the `method name` is the `field name` and `method returned value` is the `field value`. For example

```
class XXXController < ApplicationController

  ..

  if a
    values = A
  elsif b
    values = B
  elseif c
    values = C
    ..
  end

  render :json => values.to_json(:methods => :type_needed)
```

and you will see response like

```
{
  ..

  "type_needed": true,

  ..
}
```

I only have type_needed defined in A which will return `true` in some cases. For others like B, C, D... which in total 19, i want them to all have type_needed returned as `false`, is there a way i can do that in one place instead of add type_needed method in the rest 19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it as follows:

```
json = values.to_json(:methods => :type_needed)
# => "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Aaa\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Bbb\"}]"   # => Representational value only

ary = JSON.parse(json)
# => [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Aaa"}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Bbb"}]

ary.map! { |hash| hash[:type_needed] = false unless hash.key?(:type_needed); hash }
# => [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Aaa", :type_needed=>false}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Bbb", :type_needed=>false}]

ary.to_json
# => "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Aaa\",\"type_needed\":false},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Bbb\",\"type_needed\":false}]"
```

Comment: Thx a lot, this is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then you want to define `type_needed` method once and have it included on all your 20 models. If yes, then you can define a concern and include it in all your 20 models.

**app/models/concerns/my_model_concern.rb**

```
module MyModelConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def type_needed?
    self.respond_to?(:some_method)
  end
end
```

**app/models/a.rb**

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  include MyModelConcern

  def some_method
  end
end
```

**app/models/b.rb**

```
class B < ApplicationRecord
  include MyModelConcern


end
```

**app/models/c.rb**

```
class C < ApplicationRecord
  include MyModelConcern


end
```

With the above

```
a = A.new
a.type_needed? 
=> true

b = B.new
b.type_needed? 
=> false

c = C.new
c.type_needed? 
=> false
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Thx for your comment :)